# Spring Lazy.of with parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wonder what can I do with existing code where method `calculateOptions` received one parameter (without any parameters before).

My code in my Spring app:

```
public class Slots{

private final Aaa aaa;
private final Lazy<Set<Option>> options =
            Lazy.of(this::calculateOptions);


public Set<Option> calculateFinalOptions(LocalDate date) { //new parameter
    return calculateOptions(date);
}

private Set<Option> calculateOptions(LocalDate date) { ///new parameter
}
```

I tried eg.

```
private final Lazy<Set<Option>> options =
            Lazy.of(() -> calculateOptions(date???));
```

but I don't have idea how to fix this to avoid compile error

Comment: Well, you'd need to get that date from somewhere and once initialized the options would depend on that date. So suppose you're doing `Lazy.of(() -> calculateOptions(LocalDate.now()))`. This would calculate options as of today but if your application is running for a longer time `options` might get outdated.

Comment: @Thomas I changed my code snippet by changing method to public -> I'm calling calculateOptions from outside with some LocalDate parameter

Comment: Well, if you're calling that method from the outside what is the `Lazy.of(this::calculateOptions)` for then? Note that calling the method here is not related to calling the method somewhere else, at least there's nothing indicating this in your code snippets.

Comment: @Thomas ok I added sth to my code -> please look at this. I'm calling some other public method that is calling my lazy method

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. This doesn't change anything. Calling any other method somewhere else isn't related to the use of  `Lazy` if the only connection is that both are using the same method. I'll repeat: `calculateOptions(LocalDate)` will be called _once_ when the `Lazy` is initialized. After that the `Set<Options>` inside the `Lazy` will exist and be returned every time you want to get the value of the `Lazy`. SO unless you're directly modifying that set or the values in it there won't be any changes after the initial call.

Comment: Let me try with another example: You're asking me what time it is but since I'm lazy I'll look at the clock only once and give the same answer every time after that (e.g. "1:30 pm"). Now _you_ are looking at the clock yourself and always get the current time. The results will be different although we're both looking at the same clock (which in your case would be the method `calculateOptions(LocalDate)`).

Comment: @Thomas ok so the solution is to just remove Lazy because in my case it is unnecessary and pointless

Comment: It seems to but I can't tell for sure. If no code is accessing `options` then sure, delete it.